# red hat - glibc version too low for a lot of needed packages

Tags: php, redhat, yum, glibc

I am running a Red Hat server with the following version:

```
webtatic-release-6-5.noarch
**redhat-release-server-6Server-6.6.0.2.el6.x86_64**
epel-release-7-2.noarch
rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.i686
remi-release-6.5-1.el6.remi.noarch
```

The problem is that if I want to install php-mcrypt(needed by the Laravel framework) by entering this command:

```
sudo yum install php-mcrypt
```

But when running this command the following problem appears:

```
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by php-mcrypt-5.4.16-2.el7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by libmcrypt-2.5.8-13.el7.x86_64
```

Which makes sense because my glib version is:

```
ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.12
```

So I tried to do a `sudo yum update --skip-broken` to somehow update that version. But even that command gives this error:

```
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by htop-1.0.3-3.el7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) is needed by htop-1.0.3-3.el7.x86_64
```

So now I am quite stuck. I am wondering if anyone else also encounters this problem on a Red Hat server and can possible provide me some help.

Comment: You shouldn't have installed the epel-release RPM for RHEL 7 on a RHEL 6 box.  You're trying to install software that's expecting newer versions than what your system has available.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I guess the server hasn't been set up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the EPEL 6 `epel-release` package, not the EPEL 7 package.

Comment: Could you expand on that? I am not quite familiar with EPEL at all. And this, what you are suggesting, feels like a downgrade?

Comment: EPEL is specific to the RHEL version you're running. You're running RHEL 6, so you need the EPEL 6 repository. It is not a downgrade, it is correcting an error. The error was installing the EPEL 7 `epel-release` package.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am googling right now on how to do this but can't find specific info. Are there any risks involved by doing this?

Comment: There is a very real risk of system corruption if you do NOT remove the EPEL 7 release package. There are no risks to isntalling EPEL 6 that you haven't already decided are worth taking.